# NX workspaces - use bootstrap scss in library

Tags: sass, nx-workspace

I would like to import scss files from bootstrap in my NX workspace.
I would need to import the `/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions` file in the `libs/folderName/components/src/lib/my-component component`

In the scss file I have this:
`@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";`

in the my-app/project.json file:

```
 "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": [
        "node_modules/bootstrap/scss"
      ]
    }
```

but when I run the application, I get an error on build:

```
Error in ./libs/folderName/components/src/lib/my-component/my-component.component.scss?ngResource

The module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: cannot find a styleset to import.
  ╷
2 │ @import "functions
```

"
│ ^^^^^^^^^^^

How to import bootstrap scss into a library in NX?